# Cant access Tizen store from the UK

Tags: tizen

I'm starting to develop some Tizen apps but wanted to access the Tizen app store on my Z1 i have in the UK, however the phone says the store isnt available form this country. Any suggestions how i can get access? e.g. root the device, VPN service etc?

Answer (score 0):

you either need an indian sim card in the phone or you need to tunnel your network. see https://www.facebook.com/TizenExperts/posts/925467737493797 for details.